# How to get the details of a class/interface just by knowing its name(not fully qualified name)

Tags: java, reflection

I just want to know that using just the name of the class/interface ( not fully qualified name),can i get the details of that class/interface i.e by using methods like `isinterface(),getSuperClass(),getInterfaces()`.

I have gone through the [Oracle Doc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#forName-java.lang.String-)  but i could not find any way.
Can someone help me with this?

Comment: Short answer - thats not how things work! After all `packages` have some significance. How do you avoid name clashes etc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, since you can't have a reference to the class with just the class name, you won't be able to execute any of those methods. Packages are there for a reason.

Answer (score 1):

You can only check your object is a instance of  ....class or ....interface by the use of instanceof operator and for other jobs go through with Java Reflection

Answer (score 1):

No, It can not be achieved without fully qualified name. To apply mentioned methods you need reference for the class and to have that reference you need fully qualified name of the class.